# How to stop my page elements from shrinking when I restore down the browser?

Tags: html, css

I know this must be something very simple but I can't find any solution that works for me. When I restore down my browser all my page elements move out of place and shrink, I want them to stay in same position and retain their size.

Here is my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>

<head>

<title> What's in the picnic basket? </title>

<link href="home.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<head>



     <body>

<div id="wrapper">


     <div class="titlebutton">
        <img src="images/Title.gif" id="titlebutton">
     </div>

     <div class="grass">
     <img src="images/Grasspatch.gif" id="grass">
     </div>




</div>

     </body>




</html>
```

and my css:

```
body{
text-align: center;
}

#wrapper{
width: 500px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: absolute;
}



.titlebutton{position: fixed;
top: 35px;
left: 340px;
z-index: 1;}

#titlebutton{
height: 75%;
width: 75%;
}

.grass {
position: fixed;
top: 140px;
left: 400px;
}

#grass{
height: 80%;
width: 80%;
}
```

Thanks a million to those who help, I'm such a coding noob :P

Comment: if none of the answers fits your needs you should try to explain in detail what you mean by "shrinking" - maybe a screenshot including a mockup of what you actually want would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the position attribute in your css. When an element is fixed, it's properties become relative to the browser window. So in your case, when the elements were fixed, they were sized to a percentage of your browser's window. By setting them to absolute, they become relative to their first static parent.

**From:**

```
.titlebutton{
    position: fixed;
    etc...
}

.grass {
   position: fixed;
   etc...
}
```

**To:**

```
 .titlebutton{
        position: absolute;
        etc...
    }

    .grass {
       position: absolute;
       etc...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to stay in the same size you will need to set their width without %

For example:

```
.#grass{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
 }
```

if you want them to resize a bit, but not over a specific limit you can use something like that:

```
#grass{
   height: 80%;
   width: 80%;
   min-width: 400px;
   min-height: 400px;
}
```

the position fixed will make them stay at their position on the screen. fixed with top 100 left 100 will be 100 from top and left of your screens corner

the same with absolute will not always be 100 from your top, because it will go up after scrolling etc.